# Calculating costs of a line geometry based on a different intersecting geometry

Tags: postgresql, intersection, st-intersects

I have 2 tables, a route table with line geometry and a duct table also with line geometry. Basically I need to calculate the costs of the different routes based on their intersection with the duct table

```
 route table 
 id integer
 geom geometry 

 duct table
 id integer
 type integer
 geom geometry
```

To explain what I needed as a query, it would be something like this:

```
select route.id ,
case when duct.type = 1 then st_length(route.geom) * 0.3 --intended here was only the intersecting part not the full length
when duct.type = 2 then then st_length(route.geom) * 0.5
else null end as cost
from route 
left join duct  on st_intersects(route.geom,duct.geom)
```

There are a few problems with the above query:

1 - since the join is based on every line that touches, it multiplies the number of routes for every duct that it touches. A route can intersect multiple ducts. I need the cost to reflect the different duct types it passes through, in a single row

2 - the cost is purely based on the intersection between both layers. So if the route table only intersects for 2 meters with the duct table but is 100 meters long, I'm getting a cost for the full 100 meters instead of the 2 meters.

3 - sometimes the duct layer has multiple geometries overlapping each other, I need to only use the cost for the one with the higher value for type and ignore the others

How to get the proper cost based exclusively on when the lines are completely intersecting and not just touching?